# SQL: multiple inner join in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, inner-join, exists

this query does not show correct result. It shows all the CustomerId.

```
select Customers.customerid, Customers.custfirstname, Customers.custlastname from customers
where exists (select * from customers c
inner join orders o on c.CUSTOMERID=o.CUSTOMERID
inner join ORDER_DETAILS od on o.ordernumber = od.ORDERNUMBER 
inner join products on products.PRODUCTNUMBER= od.PRODUCTNUMBER
where products.CATEGORYID= 2 and o.customerid = o.customerid);
```

the above result is

```
CUSTOMERID CUSTFIRSTNAME             CUSTLASTNAME            
---------- ------------------------- -------------------------
      1001 Suzanne                   Viescas                  
      1002 William                   Thompson                 
      1003 Gary                      Hallmark                 
      1004 Robert                    Brown                    
      1005 Dean                      McCrae                   
      1006 John                      Viescas                  
      1007 Mariya                    Sergienko                
      1008 Neil                      Patterson                
      1009 Andrew                    Cencini                  
      1010 Angel                     Kennedy                  
      1011 Alaina                    Hallmark                 
      1012 Liz                       Keyser                   
      1013 Rachel                    Patterson                
      1014 Sam                       Abolrous                 
      1015 Darren                    Gehring                  
      1016 Jim                       Wilson                   
      1017 Manuela                   Seidel                   
      1018 David                     Smith                    
      1019 Zachary                   Ehrlich                  
      1020 Joyce                     Bonnicksen               
      1021 Estella                   Pundt                    
      1022 Caleb                     Viescas                  
      1023 Julia                     Schnebly                 
      1024 Mark                      Rosales                  
      1025 Maria                     Patterson                
      1026 Kirk                      DeGrasse                 
      1027 Luke                      Patterson                
      1028 Jeffrey                   Tirekicker               

 28 rows selected
```

I made same meaning of the above query;this query shows correct result.
It shows the result that the customer who only bought products.CATEGORYID= 2

```
select distinct c.customerid, c.custfirstname, c.custlastname from customers c
inner join orders o on o.customerid=c.CUSTOMERID
inner join ORDER_DETAILS od on od.ORDERNUMBER=o.ORDERNUMBER
inner join products p on p.PRODUCTNUMBER=od.productnumber
where  p.CATEGORYID= 2 
order by 1;
```

the correct result is

```
   CUSTOMERID CUSTFIRSTNAME             CUSTLASTNAME            
    ---------- ------------------------- -------------------------
          1002 William                   Thompson                 
          1004 Robert                    Brown                    
          1005 Dean                      McCrae                   
          1006 John                      Viescas                  
          1007 Mariya                    Sergienko                
          1008 Neil                      Patterson                
          1009 Andrew                    Cencini                  
          1010 Angel                     Kennedy                  
          1011 Alaina                    Hallmark                 
          1012 Liz                       Keyser                   
          1013 Rachel                    Patterson                
          1014 Sam                       Abolrous                 
          1016 Jim                       Wilson                   
          1017 Manuela                   Seidel                   
          1018 David                     Smith                    
          1019 Zachary                   Ehrlich                  
          1020 Joyce                     Bonnicksen               
          1021 Estella                   Pundt                    
          1023 Julia                     Schnebly                 
          1024 Mark                      Rosales                  
          1025 Maria                     Patterson                
          1026 Kirk                      DeGrasse                 
          1027 Luke                      Patterson                

     23 rows selected
```

what is the problem in the first query?

Comment: `EXISTS` checks to see if there are ANY results in your subquery. You subquery returns records since at least one customer bought in that CategoryID so all records pass the test in the outer query. It looks like you were trying to do a correlated subquery with that `o.customerid = o.customerid` but that is nonsense. `o.customerid = o.customerid` is ALWAYS true. Instead maybe: `customer.customerid = o.customerid` so you compare the outer queries customer table to the inner query's `o` table.

Comment: inner join orders o on c.CUSTOMERID=o.CUSTOMERID  part  covers  customer.customerid = o.customerid part. So the result is the same. When I get rid of " and o.customerid = o.customerid" part, the result is the same. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

As JNevill pointed out, `EXISTS` will return true if there is any result in the sub-query. If you change this to be:

```
SELECT c.customerid, c.custfirstname, c.custlastname 
FROM customers AS c
WHERE c.customerid IN ( SELECT  [subquery here...] 
                        WHERE products.CATEGORYID = 2)
```

Your subquery does not need `o.customerid = o.customerid` as this looks like a typo instead of `o.customerid = c.customerid` and this is covered in your `INNER JOIN` condition.

****Edit [Exists version]****

```
SELECT  c1.customerid,
        c1.custfirstname,
        c1.custlastname
FROM    customers AS c1
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM   customers c2
                 INNER JOIN orders o ON c2.CUSTOMERID = o.CUSTOMERID
                 INNER JOIN ORDER_DETAILS od ON o.ordernumber = od.ORDERNUMBER
                 INNER JOIN products ON products.PRODUCTNUMBER = od.PRODUCTNUMBER
                 WHERE  products.CATEGORYID = 2 AND c2.customerid = c.customerid )
```

The best way would just be your subquery on its own:

```
SELECT  c.customerid,
        c.custfirstname,
        c.custlastname
FROM    customers AS c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.CUSTOMERID = o.CUSTOMERID
INNER JOIN ORDER_DETAILS od ON o.ordernumber = od.ORDERNUMBER
INNER JOIN products ON products.PRODUCTNUMBER = od.PRODUCTNUMBER
WHERE   products.CATEGORYID = 2
```

Comment: Thank you!  it works. But is there any way that I can use EXISTS instead  WHERE IN?

Comment: I've added 2 more solutions to my first answer, one including the EXISTS.
I wouldn't recommend it though, because the simplest way to do this is without the subquery at all :)

Comment: Thanks for helping me. This was my first question. I appreciate your help.